# how to port Snort on Android OS

Tags: android, port, cross-compiling, android-ndk, snort

Is there a way to port Snort to Android OS? I have already ported
libpcap to Android and I have made some simple native sniffers which worked
perfectly.To do this, I used the NDK development kit that offers you some
tools for cross compiling C programs to ARM architecture.

Is this possible to do it for Snort. I know that Snort is a big project that
contains many source files and uses many modules such as Libpcap, PCRE,
Libdnet, Barnyard2, DAQ. I am wondering if is there a way to build
this code for Android.. E.g. by statically link all this modules.. Moreover an
other potential problem may be the fact that Android uses a subset of libc
(bionic), so maybe some basic functions are not available..

Have anyone done it before? Or, can some one give me some help on how
to start?

Comment: I have already ported Libpcap, PCRE, Libdnet and DAQ. I couldn't do the same for Barnyard2.. Moreover I tried to put them all together with Snort.. without success..

Answer (score 0):

Lack of exception handling and STL was very painful when i ported using NDK. As snort is C based, that shouldn't be the case. I guess unicode handling (as ndk doesnt support wide char functionality) can get tricky.